# Multi page template in jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I create my pages using multi page template, I read that only start page(e.g index.aspx) still remain in Dom in each pages when loading. but now in my other page(e.g child.aspx) which is a child of page parent.aspx, I can see dom element of parent.aspx page. 
the breadcrumb is as follow: Index--->parent--->child, maybe I should see only the index dom content not parent. this make me wonder why the page is like this and how I can handle it.Thanks

## update:

I just want to reload every page on each showing, I mean clearing the DOM completely and loading content from the beginning. Like when you push ctrl+f5 and load page without cache. Is this possible in JQM?

**Index.aspx:**

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" dir="rtl">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode = "Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <uc2:MblMyMessageBox ID="MblMyMessageBoxInfo" runat="server" ShowCloseButton="true" /> 
    <div data-role="page" id="home"> 
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="AccountStatus.aspx">AccountStatus</a></li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="ConfirmPayment.aspx">ConfirmPayment</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**AccountStatus.aspx:**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="accountStatus">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="BalancePage.aspx" data-prefetch="true">balance</a></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="InvoicePage.aspx">invoice</a></li>
        </ul>           
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <p><a href="Index.aspx">back</a></p>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
 </div><!-- /page -->
```

removing content of index from accountStatus page dom element is my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All pages that the user has navigated to will be added to the dom. See [the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html). However jQM also has [a mechanism](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html) to keep the DOM from getting to big and slowing down the browser. It may or may not remove old elements from the DOM.
I would advice you not to trust on DOM elements getting removed automatically. If you really want to remove the page you are navigating away from, you can bind for example the following:

```
$(document).one("pageshow",function(){
     $(document).one("pagehide",function(){
          $("#pageId").remove();
     });
});
```

Where pageId is the id you give to the `<div data-role="page" id="pageId">`.

Edit for the updated question:
To reload the whole page when following links:

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition.

Source: [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Or you can change it with the [following global variable](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html):

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I did what you said but the problem still remains and content from other page holds its place as hidden divs. you know when I refresh the current page everything is ok but in navigating way this issue occurs. I double check ID of divs and found that having the same <form id=""> in my asp page also is wrong. I changed it too but this dosent solve it yet.

Comment: So the div with the `id="pageId"` isn't removed from the DOM. So probably the function `.remove()` isn't called at all or isn't called on the right element. Could you check if it is either of these cases?

Comment: Thank you so much Calavoow, you help me a lot. data-ajax="false" is the answer.